# ShellExecute utilizando o CMD para abrir o mysql

Tags: mysql, delphi

Senhores, gostaria de lhes perguntar se tem como utilizar o comando `cmd` para rodar o mysql.exe nele, deixem-me utilizar uma linha de código:

```
ShellExecute(Handle,'open',PChar('cmd.exe'),PWideChar('/k cd\mysql\bin & mysql.exe --host 192.168.0.50 --user root --database=sinval --password= Repair Table item'), nil, SW_SHOW);
```

Quero que na ultima passagem de parâmetro do ShellExecute(), ele execute um comando sql, sendo mais claro, gostaria que ficasse tipo assim:

```
ShellExecute(Handle,'open',PChar('cmd.exe'),PWideChar('/k **Comando cmd & comando para entrar no mysql | comando sql**'), nil, SW_SHOW);
```

Então, o que acham? Há uma forma melhor de fazer isto? Se não entenderem, por favor falem, tentarei ver uma melhor explicação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa passar a opção `-e` ou `--execute` seguida do comando que quer executar. Por exemplo:

```
mysql.exe --host 192.168.0.50 --user root --database=sinval --password=bla --execute "SELECT * FROM tbl"
```

Comment: Caramba, funcionou perfeitamente, Obrigado!!!